AWS lambda is limited to 30 event trigger
In my use case, I want to trigger a lambda function with a different payload 26 days a month at 2 different times.
My idea was to create a total of 52 EventBridge triggers for this. After creating the 29th trigger, I have now received the following error message:

The final policy size (20755) is bigger than the limit (20480).

Each event has its own resource. The limit seems to be exhausted very quickly. Is there a way to create more events for a lambda?

UPDATE
This should be the following execution interval:
Day 1: 1 am with payload={1}
Day 1: 1 pm with payload={2}
Day 2: 2 am with payload={3}
Day 2: 2 pm with payload={4}
Day 3: 3 am with payload={5}
Day 3: 3 pm with payload={6}
...
Day 26


I'm not sure what you mean by "26 days a week at 2 different times", but an alternative is to trigger it at a regular time (eg hourly) and then the Lambda function can figure out whether it should run (or exit immediately) and what it should do. This makes the trigger very simple and the execution logic can be in the Lambda function rather than EventBridge.

Pls provide more detail about your usecase, if all 52 event need to have different payload then I think that you're using wrong services for your usecase. In addition, EB scheduler can be configured with cron expression, try to use it instead

Are you sure you cannot write a more concise crontab expression?

What specifically is different about the payload of each EventBridge trigger? I would think about having one or two triggers that trigger every day, and have the Lambda function check the current date/time to determine what it needs to do instead of relying on EventBridge payloads.

I have updated my question with the required interval. I really like the idea of integrating the execution logic into the lambda function. Is it possible to increment the execution time to have it like in my example?
